# Why is the cursor shaking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

My marker has a problem that when I do `mouse:hover` the cursor is shaking.

I put my component into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-glade-d8hfv?file=/src/App.js) with the same code I'm using on my application.

You may notice when you bring the mouse closer to the edge of the marker, the cursor starts to shaking.

```css
.marker {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #61ba9e;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.marker:hover {
  height: 12.5px;
  width: 12.5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgb(97 186 158 / 60%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="marker"></div>
```

I don't know why this is happening, can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Because the edge of the marker moves away from the hand as the circle gets smaller, which causes it to disengage from the hand and cause the circle to become larger, which causes it to engage with the hand again and become smaller, etc.

Comment: Because the marker shrinks away from the cursor, making the cursor not hover anymore, making the marker grow again, which makes the cursor hover again…

Comment: The problem is that as soon as you hover on the edge the size is dimished, so the cursor isn't hovering anymore, so the size goes back up, so it hovers again and so it goes on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shaking is caused by your element shrinking and therefore your cursor not hovering anymore (and then re-growing as you aren't hovering, causing your cursor to change again)

Instead of changing the size of your marker, why not use a pseudo element, then your hand won't "shake" as it will always hover the marker (but the pseudo element will change size instead).

```css
.marker {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.marker:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marker:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #61ba9e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.marker:hover:after {
  height: 12.5px;
  width: 12.5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgb(97 186 158 / 60%);
}
```

```html
<div class="marker"></div>
```

Comment: I was putting together a solution with a wrapper but using the pseudo-elements is the way to go here. +1.

Answer (score 1):

It's shaking because your object is originally 20x20 pixels in size. Once it your mouse `:hover`'s it shrinks in size.

Since the cursor is not perfectly centered on the object it reaches a point where the mouse is out of the bounding box of your element, which restores it's original width... which then makes it bigger and the mouse it's again inside the bounding box...

You see where this is going right? We have an infinite loop of shrinking and growing the element's bounding box.

A trick for getting around this may be to provide a wrapper that stays in size `20x20` and have the marker respond to the wrapper being `:hover`'ed